# Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher in git bash

Tags: windows, maven, git-bash

I haven configured maven 3.3.9 on my windows 10 machine. If i run `mvn -version` on cmd it shows me the version. But if i run the same command on git bash, i am getting following error:

```
$ mvn -version
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
```

I have set the `M2_HOME` & `MAVEN_HOME` system variable & added `%M2_HOME%\bin` on the path variable as well. How can make this work on git bash. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Removed M2_HOME, MAVEN_HOME and add only the bin directory to your path nothing else...

Comment: did not work...